# Forwarding a textbox value into another hidden textbox in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 textboxes , one of them is hidden . On clicking submit , the value entered in first textbox should pass on to the next textbox which is hidden .

Here is my code ,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
   <script>
   $(function(){
    $('#textbox1').blur(function() {
        $('input[name=textbox2]').($('#textbox1').val());

    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <input name="textbox1" type="text" class="inputext" value=""  style="cursor: text" id="textbox1" />
<input name="textbox2" type="hidden" class="inputext" value=""  style="cursor: text" id="textbox2" />
<input name="Add" type="button" value="Add" id="btn"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Any reason for doing this? :-S Why do you need the hidden if you already got the value?

Comment: "On clicking submit , the value entered in first textbox should pass on to the next textbox which is hidden ." is this on the same form? if so what's the point..

Comment: Even i don't know what's the point but the task has been assigned to me :(

Comment: is this for the purpose of displaying it only? because on the other hand you can just capture what was the value of the 1st textbox serverside to equal both

Comment: Yes , the output should be displayed in the log . None the less , it got answered :) Thanks anyways .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your code:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Contact Form</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
       <script>
       $(function(){
        $('#textbox1').blur(function() {
            $('input[name=textbox2]').attr('value',$('#textbox2').val()+$('#textbox1').val());
    console.log($('#textbox2').val());
        });

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <input name="textbox1" type="text" class="inputext" value=""  style="cursor: text" id="textbox1" />
    <input name="textbox2" type="hidden" class="inputext" value=""  style="cursor: text" id="textbox2" />
    <input name="Add" type="button" value="Add" id="btn"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What should i do if i have to continously append values to second textbox values from 1 ?

Comment: $('input[name=textbox2]').attr('value',$('#textbox2').val()+$('#textbox1').val());

Comment: it isn't adding the earlier typed values , it's just replacing .

Comment: What changes shud i do ?

Comment: function:
function change(){
  $('input[name=textbox2]').attr('value',$('#textbox1').val());
    console.log($('#textbox2').val());}
input:
<input name="textbox1" type="text" class="inputext" value="" onkeyup='change();'  style="cursor: text" id="textbox1" />

Comment: Could you give an example for your problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46332/discussion-between-kdp-and-umurbem)

Comment: If i type in abcd , the textbox shows abcd . But wen i clear and type def , it prints just def . I want to see abcdef

Answer (score 0):

you missed val() function

**Sample**

```
    $('#textbox1').blur(function() {
       $('#textbox2').val($(this).val());
   });
```

Comment: It's doing the same thing that was happening before , just passing the value with 1st textbox . textbox 2 remains blank in the url.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <script>  
      $(document).ready(function() { 
       $('#btn').click(function() {
       var textbox1=$("#textbox1").val(); 
        $("#textbox2").val(textbox1);
            });  }); 
</script>

<form>
    <input name="textbox1" type="text" class="inputext" value=""  style="cursor: text" id="textbox1" />
<input name="textbox2" type="text" class="inputext" value=""  style="cursor: text" id="textbox2" />
<input name="Add" type="button" value="Add" id="btn"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Your code did it too but umurbem's answer was to the point . The answer got shown in the log via firebug . Thanks for helping :)

Comment: What should i do if i have to continously append values to second textbox values from 1 ?